# Mock firebase.auth() persistence

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs

I was quietly creating a mock for `firebase.auth()` when I see this piece of code:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
```

So I mocked `auth` method like this:

```
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => ({
   auth: () => ({
       setPersistence: () => // blabla...
   })
}));
```

But obviously Jest complained about an undefined `firebase.auth.Auth`

aaand ok, I see, but how can I add a property to a function that can be accessed that way?

I've tried also with a this

```
function auth() {
    if (!(this instanceof auth)) return new auth();
    this.Auth = {
        Persistence: {
            LOCAL: '_',
            SESSION: '_',
        },
    };
    this.setPersistence = Promise.resolve();
}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I realized what I was missing. This is my implementation

```js
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => ({
    auth: function auth() {
        auth.Auth = {
            Persistence: {
                LOCAL: '_',
                SESSION: '_',
            },
        };

        return {
            setPersistence: () => Promise.resolve(),
            signInWithEmailAndPassword: (email, password) =>
                new Promise<void>((res, rej) => { /* ...code */}),
        };
    },
}));
```

```js
console.log(auth()); // {setPersistence: Promise, signInWithEmailAndPassword: ƒ signInWithEmailAndPassword()}
console.log(auth.Auth) // {Persistence: Object}
```